# Envio de items a la base de datos desde un Array MultiChoice de manera individual

Tags: android-studio, arraylist, multichoice

no soy programador, pero tengo una duda y no encuentro donde responderla.

Tengo un array multichoice, 
Resulta que cuando obtengo los "checkeables" puedo verlos en un solo String.
Quisiera que cada item que este con su "check" se guardara en un objeto distinto, o si existe alguna manera de separar los String del unico textView para luego ser enviados a la base de datos, estaría genial.

El problema que tengo es que todo lo que selecione me lo coloca en el TextView de forma lineal separados con coma, y quisiera que además de eso, pueda guardarlos de forma independiente en la base de datos.
Estoy utilizando AndroidStudio, y la base de datos es Firebase Realtime Database

Ojalá alguno me pueda ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

```js
   profTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Perfil.this);
                mBuilder.setTitle(R.string.profesi_n);
                mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(listItems, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked){
                            mProfesionItems.add(position);
                        }else{
                            mProfesionItems.remove((Integer.valueOf(position)));
                        }
                    }
                });

                mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                mBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                        String item = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < mProfesionItems.size(); i++) {
                            item = item + listItems[mProfesionItems.get(i)];
                            if (i != mProfesionItems.size() - 1) {
                                item = item + ", ";

                            }
                        }

                        profTextView.setText(item);                        
                        dataReference.child("perfiles").child(user_id).child("profesion").setValue(profTextView);
                    }
                });
AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listo, ya logré lo que quería muchas gracias, no se como poner como resuelto esto. Comparto igualmente por si en algún momento de la vida alguien en años si sigue esto, tal vez le sirva.
Saludos.

```
mBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {

                    String item = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < mProfesionItems.size(); i++) {
                        String guardarItem = listItems[mProfesionItems.get(i)];
                        item = item + listItems[mProfesionItems.get(i)];
                        if (i != mProfesionItems.size() - 1) {
                            item = item + ", ";
                        }
                        dataReference.child("profesiones").child(guardarItem).setValue(user_id);
                    }

                     profTextView.setText(item);

                    String prof= profTextView.getText().toString();
                    dataReference.child("perfiles").child(user_id).child("profesion").setValue(prof);
                }
            });
```

Comment: recuerda que si esto resolvió tu problema debes aceptar tu respuesta dando clic en la palomita de a lado para indicarnos a los demás que ya lo pudiste hacer y calificartela

Comment: ah okay, me dice que tengo que esperar 2 días, asi que en 2 días lo pondré como resuelta. muchas gracias